# Optimise the function to render the option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The current function is as follows

```
renderOption: (optionProps, option) => {
      // Invoke any renderOption passed from the component
      if (renderOption) {
        return renderOption(optionProps, option);
      }

      // Return default render option
      return <li {...optionProps}>{option[optionValueKey]}</li>;
    },
```

Is there a way to simplify this? Something like

```
renderOption: renderOption || (optionProps, option) => {
      return <li {...optionProps}>{option[optionValueKey]}</li>;
    },
```

Looks like some syntax error when i try to simplify this.

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt? With the rather limited context included in the question, that looks like it should be viable.

Comment: If the original code works as designed, then what problem are you trying to solve with this "optimization"?

Comment: Ah, with regards to the syntax error, I imagine you just need to wrap your arrow function in brackets. E.g. `a || (() => {})`

Comment: @DBS looks like some syntax error. I have attached the image for your reference.

Comment: i would suggest [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), ie `renderOption ?? ((optionProps, option) => ...)`. it is more precise, correct than using `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want't to keep the `renderOption`, or assign a new (arrow) function, you can use the [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)
 to fallback to the arrow function if `renderOption` is `null` or `undefined`.

Don't forget to wrap you arrow function in `()` to ensure the function itself is assigned to `renderOption`

```
renderOption: renderOptions ?? ((optionProps, option) => <li {...optionProps}>{option[optionValueKey]}</li>)
```

Comment: `??` is better suited for this

Comment: Completely agree @Mulan, changed my answer. thanks.